# swf not transparent + div opacity chrome & opera on osx

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, swfobject

Ok i got some weird stuff here I just no clue anymore.

**First** my swf file not going transparent, even when ensure wmode is transparent. non off the browsers is working... the swf is embedded but is not transparent. i even tried removing some params, but still the same... so what's wrong?

```
<div id="flashContent">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


                var flashvars = {};
                flashvars.domain = "*";
                var params = {};
                params.movie = "myflash.swf";
                params.quality = "best";
                params.play = "true";
                params.loop = "false";
                params.menu = "false";
                params.wmode = "transparent";
                params.bgcolor = "#626262";
                params.scale = "noscale";
                params.allowfullscreen = "false";
                params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
                params.allownetworking = "all";
                var attributes = {};
                attributes.id = "myflash";
                swfobject.embedSWF("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/include/myflash.swf", "flashContent", "100", "100", "10.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);



        </script>

    </div>
```

**second**
so i was going to use css to force the div to go transparent using opacity modes.
ha, but chrome & opera on the Mac OSX not going opacity at all ><

I even force them using important, and tried all possible codes i know...

```
-webkit-opacity: 0 !important; -moz-opacity: 0 !important; -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)" !important; filter: alpha(opacity=0) !important; opacity: 0 !important;
```

*well any have a clue what i am doing wrong?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because your passing the params object in the wrong spot

```
swfobject.embedSWF("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/include/myflash.swf", "flashContent", "100", "100", "10.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Try this:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/include/myflash.swf", "flashContent", 100, 100, "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes, false);
```

Comment: thanks shaz! That did the job. Where stands the two false for?

Comment: @Cam: Take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#STEP_3:_Embed_your_SWF_with